# Fluro keeps returning null value on variable (trying to get parameters from url)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Im trying to accept parameters from url, but when i enter the url `/id/123` the page i get null value from the variable in CounterView pages id variable.
Heres my code.
What am i doing wrong?

Main.Dart

```
void main() {
  FluroRouter.setupRouter();
  runApp(MainPage());
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: FluroRouter.router.generator,
      home: MainWindow()
    );
  }
}
```

fluro_router.Dart

```
class FluroRouter {
  static Router router = Router();

  static Handler _MainWindowhandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          MainWindow());

  static Handler _CounterViewhandler = Handler(
      handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) =>
          CounterView(id: params["id"][0]));

  static void setupRouter() {
    router.define(
      '/',
      handler: _MainWindowhandler,
    );

    router.define(
      '/id/:id',
      handler: _CounterViewhandler,
    );
  }
}
```

CounterView.Dart

````
class CounterView extends StatelessWidget {
  CounterView({String id});
  String id;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(id);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Can you explain how you enter the url /id/123?

Comment: I just enter it in url bar.

Comment: Could it be that you try to integrate deeplinks into your project? It could be that you mix deeplink with page routes. For deeplinks I recommended to have a look at the package [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).